# Update Azure DevOps artifact properties using API call

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, devops-services

Does anyone know here how to update an Artifact's properties? We've had a project assigned to us to move all of our artifact drops from one location to another - This is because our file server is about to die (We use On-Prem Azure DevOps Services)

I've wrote a PowerShell script already that updates what's needed for builds/releases and that works great.

So I wrote another PowerShell script to update what's needed within the Artifacts properties and then uses an "PUT" call to replace the info but there's an issue....

`Invoke-RestMethod : {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."}}`

Does anyone know if this is possible/knows how to do it?

Here's my script;

Example of an endpoint;

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?api-version=5.1
```

```
$artefacts = Get-Content ".\artefacts.txt"
$oldDataURL = "\\rdtstore01.main.rdt.co.uk\Horizon\Drops"
$newDataURL = "\\main.rdt.co.uk\shares\Horizon\Drops"

foreach ($line in $artefacts)
{

    $var = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $line -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get

    ### Updte Data line ###
    $data = $var.value.resource.data
    $dataNew = $data -replace [RegEx]::Escape($oldDataURL), $newDataURL
    $var.value.resource.data = @{}
    $var.value.resource.data += @{"value" = $dataNew}
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $line -Method Put -ContentType "application/json" -UseDefaultCredentials -Body (ConvertTo-Json $var -Depth 10)
}
```

Comment: Can you show what endpoint you are hitting?

Comment: If you check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) you will see that `PUT` is not supported. So basically this is not possible in a way you are trying to do.

Comment: I saw :/  Just wondering if anyone has come up with a different solution to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Rest API to update Artifacts properties is not support right now.  We only provide below methods for working with artifacts produced by builds.

[image]

Sorry, there is not any workaround, you may have to use build task to publish artifacts again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have an open ticket with MS. Apparently there maybe something we can do using the database. But lets wait and see what happens.